# background not visible on LG G3

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a fragment with FrameLayout, the background of the layout is set to a drawable resource which was imported for all screen densities (from mdpi to xxx-hdpi).

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.package.MyFragment"
android:background="@drawable/roads_grey">

some views...

</FrameLayout>
```

for some reason the background is not visible on LG G3. It is visible on Oneplus One, Pixel XL, 6P and nexus 5X (which has the same screen density as the G3).

What may be the cause of this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple - the assets resolution was too large, after resizing it was displayed correctly.